# Why is echo b"foo"; legal php code? What is the purpose of the b?

Tags: php

This statement is perfectly working:

```
<?php
    echo b"foo";
```

What is the purpose of the b?

Comment: Fun fact: There was even a [`is_binary()`](https://web.archive.org/web/20090125013821/http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-binary.php) function once.

Comment: @Rizier123 this may just make it in to my test for our new php developer

Comment: @Dagon That would be a bit mean ;) There is only one sentence dedicated to `(binary)`/`b` in the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php#language.types.typecasting). Maybe you should just ask them how they would search for it, what they would do to find out what it is.

Comment: @Dagon Don't forget to ask them, why this url: https://3v4l.org/3GOW8 is valid PHP :P

Comment: @Rizier123 problem occurs when im expected to explain it!

Comment: @Dagon I will leave you now with that mystery :p

Comment: @Rizier123 bastard!

Comment: lol thanks for your comments - Dragon, yes, I will certainly ask ;-)

Comment: @Dagon One hint: [Labels](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.goto.php) + [Comments](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.comments.php)